# Customer Portal My Documents Grid Selection

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to do a custom action (“PAY”, “CONFIRM PAYMENT”)  in the screen SP402000 in the Acumatica Customer Portal that creates a transaction in the ERP. At the moment the action I created works for all records in the following grid. I am currently missing the part in which I can select the records that I want to process in the grid. I tried adding a check box column and changing the Skin ID of the grid from PrimaryInquiry to Primary so I can try to edit the records but it didn’t work.

Any ideas on how I can make that checkbox editable?

[acumatica screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Qrl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a graph extension for the graph and add the following row selected event handler. (Leave the skinid as primaryinquire)

```
protected void _(Events.RowSelected<TheGridDAC> e, PXRowSelected baseHandler)
{
    if (e.Row is null) return;
    baseHandler.Invoke(e.Cache, e.Args);
    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<TheGridDACExt.selected>(e.Cache, null)
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped. I added the code Base.Documents.Cache.AllowUpdate = true; with yours and worked.